# ASPNET MVC LabelFor or EditorFor using for loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, editorfor

I am new to ASPNET MVC. I have searched many hours but couldn't find a way to solve my simple problem.

For a Model with properties like "property1" "property2" "property3", I want to simplify the code in a View to something like:

```
for (i = 1; i <=3; i++) {
    @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.["property"+i];
}
```

How to replace the expression with custom names?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your entity has so many properties? Yipes!

Comment: actually there are 10 fields for attachment input. client wants them to be put in jquery tabs. i just wonder if it is possible to avoid 10 duplicated codes with just the number changes. (:

Comment: Why not create one property which is a collection (i.e. array or list) of a type and loop through that.

Comment: is it possible to store an array of a type to database? the program is using ef db first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the weakly typed version :

```
for (i = 1; i <=3; i++) {
    @Html.Editor("property"+i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps. is there no way to use strongly typed?